# Addons aren't displayed in Firefox

Tags: browser-addons, firefox, firebug

Hai guys,
         I have webdeveloper and firebug addon installed in my mozilla firefox... I was using these addons for a month or two... But now it cant be viewed in my browser... When i checked addons in tools i found these two addons... I dont know what is the reason....

Comment: what version of firefox your are using ?

Comment: firefox 3.5.1 ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest re-installing Firefox and seeing if the problem persists could be a corrupt file etc